# How to retrieve "Human Readable" strings from Locale strings like systeminfo.exe displays?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, locale, native

```
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
```

When you run systeminfo.exe the useful information includes the above two lines.  Does a Windows API or C runtime function provide the string **English (United States)**?

Comment: Could be very well located in the registry somewhere. I know .net can show you. But I do not know what happens in the background of .net when requesting the locale. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.englishname.aspx You could use CurrentCulture.DisplayName/EnglishName/Name

Comment: Mikes comment led me to this and the fact that I had completely missed the "GetLocaleInfoEx" method that was right infront of my eyes!

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649676/c-win32-api-equivalent-of-cultureinfo-twoletterisolanguagename][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649676/c-win32-api-equivalent-of-cultureinfo-twoletterisolanguagename

Answer (score 0):

It can do with `GetLocaleInfo`. LCTYPE is LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE / LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY, i guess.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main() {
  char language[256] = {0}, country[256] = {0};
  GetLocaleInfo(
    GetUserDefaultLCID(),
    LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE,
    language,
    sizeof(language));
  GetLocaleInfo(
    GetUserDefaultLCID(),
    LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY,
    country,
    sizeof(country));
  printf("%s (%s)\n", language, country);
}
// I got "Japanese (Japan)"
```